# How to do regexp replace/search

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

I am following some instructions for data upload. I can't figure out what the following two points mean. Does anyone have any idea?

1. Regexp search/replace

   - search: `201([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9][0-9])    ([0-9])`
   - `replace:201\1\2\3\4        \5`
2. Regexp search/replace

   - replace `20110401` with whatever year month day that is being fixed
     `^(.{462})`
     `\120110401`

Comment: I have tried to fix the formatting of your question, but I think the last part is wrong. Please [edit] it and fix any mistakes I might have made. Also, please add a tag for whatever language or tool you are trying to use to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any decent regex tutorial [will](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) [help](https://regexone.com).

`()` wrap groups that can be referenced later with `\#`. For example, `\2` references the token matched by the second pair of parentheses.

`[0-9]` means any character between 0-9 inclusive.

`^` is the left anchor (i.e., start of string or new line), and `.{462}` means any character, 462 times.